# Multiple setimeout in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to two event after a delay of time. First is click a button that I hide and then redirect the page. I tried each one, it worked normally. But when I combine them together it's not working anymore.

```
<a href="<?php echo $model->link; ?>">
  <button id="button" style="width:0px; height:0px;" class="btn btn-success"></button>
</a>

window.setTimeout(function() {

    document.getElementById("button").click();

}, 3000);

window.setTimeout(function() {

    window.location = "<?php echo Url::to(['index', 'id' => $model->cate_id]); ?>";

}, 3000);
```

I tried to write it like this

```
window.setTimeout(function() {

    document.getElementById("button").click();
    window.location = "<?php echo Url::to(['index', 'id' => $model->cate_id]); ?>";

}, 3000);
```

But still it just redirect the page and not click the button.

Please help me with this, thank you

Comment: It might click the button, it might not.  But you wouldn't be able to tell because you have told it to redirect to another page at the exact same time.  Maybe try and do your button click after say 2 seconds,  and then your redirect after 3 to give the button chance to do something.

Comment: I tried, button click after 1 second and redirect after 4 second, still not click

Comment: Why are you redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the button is not something a user can click since you are manually triggering the click event. So try it this way:

```
    <a href="<?php echo $model->link; ?>">
      <button id="button" style="width:0px; height:0px;" class="btn btn-success" onclick="redirect()"></button>
    </a>

    window.setTimeout(function() {

        document.getElementById("button").click();

    }, 3000);

    function redirect() {
         window.location = "<?php echo Url::to(['index', 'id' => $model->cate_id]); ?>";
    }
```

Attach an onclick event to the button to trigger the page redirect.